# Unit test cannot find a file when run by Azure Devops Server agent

Tags: azure-devops

In `app.config` file there is a reference to another config file.

```
<system.web>
    <roleManager configSource="Roles.config"/>
```

When the test case is executed from Visual Studio everything works fine. But if it is run from Azure Devops Server by the self-hosted agent it throws the following exception:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unable to open configSource file 'Roles.config'.
```

The file is always copied to bin directory.

Any ideas?

Update:
After some investigation it turned out that there is no `Roles.config` file in the temporary work folder: `agent\_work\2\s\TestResults\Deploy_srv 2020-05-15 14_46_18\Out\`

A small part of the YAML

```
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Test Assemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\$(BuildConfiguration)\One.dll
     **\$(BuildConfiguration)\Two.dll
```

Comment: Could you share some details about your pipeline definitions and test project itself so that we can reproduce the issue? A minimal reproducible sample?

Comment: For now I use the default asp.net template with a few assemblies listed that contain unit test.

Comment: Your yaml looks right without any mistake, it could not be the cause. Set the variable `System.Debug=true` and run the pipeline again, then share the detailed log here using github link, then we can check it more directly~

Comment: I did a lot of investigation and there are weird things going on. I've got about 10 assemblies with tests and I noticed that if I use only one of them (the one with this failing test) then everything works fine.

Comment: How about separating the test assemblies into two test tasks? One task for those who don't have config files and one for the failed test...

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas?

Maybe you can check these tips for a trouble-shooting:

1.First you should make sure the `Roles.config` file is under Version Control.

2.Then make sure this file's Copy option is set to copy always, check your project file(xx.xxproj) and check if it exists:

```
<xxx Include="Roles.config">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</xxx>
```

3.Since the `configSource` attribute uses relative path, you should make sure the `Roles.config` file is under same directory as your app.config file.

Comment: 1. Yes it is.
2. Yes it is copied to the output bin directory

Comment: Hi drv, how does your pipeline looks like? If convenient, can you share some details about your pipeline and a minimal sample(deleting personal info and core code) about your project to reproduce the issue? Then I can reproduce the issue on my side and check it directly for you~

Comment: I'll check that and come back as soon as possible :)

Comment: Any info on this? having the same issue with .NET core 8 and Xunit